# How to perform periodic work on an ASP.NET MVC website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Once a day, I want my ASP.NET MVC4 website, which may be running on multiple servers, to email a report to me.  This seems like a pretty common thing to want to do, but I'm having a tough time coming up with a good way to do it.

Trying to run a timer on a server to do this work is problematic for a couple of reasons.  If I have multiple servers then I'd have the timer running on all of them (in case a server goes down); I'd need to coordinate between them, which gets complicated.  Also, trying to access the database via Entity Framework from a background thread adds the complication that I must employ a locking strategy to serialize construction/disposal of the DbContext object between the periodic background thread and the "foreground" Controller thread.

Another option would be to run a timer on the servers, but to have the timer thread perform a GET to a magic page that generates and emails the report.  This solves the DbContext problem because the database accesses happen in a normal Controller action, serialized with all of the other Controller accesses to the database.  But I'm still stuck with the problem of having potentially more than one timer running, so I'd need some smarts in the Controller action to ignore redundant report requests.

Any suggestions?  How is this sort of thing normally done?

Comment: The quick answer is that you shouldn't be doing this from the website. The simplest solution would be to create an executable to do the work for you and schedule it with the task scheduler. There are plenty of variations on this depending on your level of complexity and need, but starting at simplest, schedule task. Don't do this via the website. Wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should not be doing this task from your web application as Phil Haack nicely explains it in [`his blog post`](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/16/the-dangers-of-implementing-recurring-background-tasks-in-asp-net.aspx).

> How is this sort of thing normally done?

You could perform this task from a Windows Service or even a console application that is scheduled to run at regular intervals using the Windows Scheduler.

Comment: And if you don't have rights on the server to set up a scheduled task, you can use a third-party service like IPPatrol to periodically make a HTTP request to your website every day or so.

Answer (score 3):

The proper solution is to create a background service that runs independently of your website. However, if that is not an option there is a hack where you can use the cache as explained in [Easy Background Tasks in ASP.NET](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/easy-background-tasks-in-aspnet/) by Jeff Atwood.

Comment: I'll note that `System.Web.Caching.Cache` uses a `System.Timers.Timer` instance internally, so you could use that directly.

Comment: Totally not recommended approach. This is still running in the web application which could be recycled by IIS at any time killing all background tasks you might have initiated. The only reliable way to achieve that is to perform those tasks out-of-process.

Answer (score 2):

A few options:

- If you are hosting on Azure as a Website, check out WebJobs which was released recently in preview (http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)
- If you don't want the pain of extracting out your email logic outside of the website, expose that functionality at a url (with a handler, mvc action, etc.) and then run a Windows Scheduled task that hits that url on a schedule.
- Write a simple console app that is executed similarly via a Windows Scheduled task.
- Or write a simple Windows Service that internally is looping and checking the time and when reached, hits that url, runs that exe, or has it's own code to send you the email.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend running Quartz.NET as a Windows Service:

[`Quartz.NET - Enterprise Job Scheduler for .NET Platform`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

There's boilerplate code for a Windows Service in the download.