# How to run a foreground scheduled task in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've this code in my `ASP.NET MVC` application to share a value across the application.

```
public static class Global
{
    public static string Token { get; private set; };

    public static void LoadFromFile()
    {
        // loads Token value from a settings file
    }
}
```

What I want to do is to run `LoadFromFile` method once a day to update the `Token` value.

I can't use a separate background task like in `HangFire`, since I want to update the value for current running application.

How can I do it? thanks.

**Update:**
Mates who think this is a duplicate, please read the question. I want to update the shared value in current running application. changing it in in a separate  background task won't change it for current application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform periodic work on an ASP.NET MVC website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859057/how-to-perform-periodic-work-on-an-asp-net-mvc-website)

Comment: @santoshsingh That's not

Comment: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/ check this link will work for u

Comment: @Saineshwar Is my question unclear Saineshwar?

Comment: quartz-scheduler allow you to write background task in asp.net mvc itself

Comment: Will the **background** task be able to change a static value of running code?

Comment: You should be looking for basic multithreading info as well as the static keyword. If you are using NET Framework you need to learn about AppDomain as well, because each AppDomain stores separate copies of static variables.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy Am I wrong in having a static property to use it in my `ASP.NET MVC` controllers?

Comment: No, you are wrong not knowing how to use them :) take it easy. Learn about relation of AppDomain and static variables. It will help.

Answer (score 0):

To help SO wandering polices rest a while, I got the answer.

I can run a scheduled background task to access an endpoint in my site, and from there update the static `Token` value.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced similar requirement once, here is the trick I used

```
    private static DateTime lastRunAt;
    private static object loadingTokenLock = new object();

    private static bool TokenUpdateNeeded
    {
        get
        {
            return DateTime.UtcNow.DayOfYear != lastRunAt.DayOfYear;
        }
    }

    public static void TryLoadToken()
    {
        if (TokenUpdateNeeded)
            lock (loadingTokenLock)
                if (TokenUpdateNeeded)
                    LoadFromFile();
    }

    public static void LoadFromFile()
    {
        // loads Token value from a settings file
        lastRunAt = DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TryLoadToken();
    }
```

I can't remember the exact coding, but the idea was to update the Token upon the first request of the day.

The problem is if your application have not been visit for more than a day, the Token will not be updated. So we defined a task in Windows Task Scheduler to visit the site once everyday

Comment: Thanks Evan. This will cause a problem if multiple users access it at the same time.

Comment: @Blendester Thanks for the comment, I have updated the code to handle concurrency. I was using different approach though. In the scheduled task that request the site periodically, I added a key in the request query string so that in the BeginRequest the request could be distincted from normal request